# Transposing music notes by scale indices

Tags: java, algorithm, audio

I'm trying to create an algorithm that transposes musical notes up or down according to their given scale and transpose factor.

**Current Algorithm:**

```
public Note getNoteByScale(Scale scale, int transposeFactor) {
    int newPitch = scale.getScaleIndex(this.pitch) + transposeFactor;
    int newOctave = this.octave;

    if (newPitch > 6) {
        newPitch -= 7;
        newOctave++;
    }
    if (newPitch < 0) {
        newPitch += 7;
    }

    return Note.createNote(scale.getNotesInScale().get(newPitch),
            newOctave, this.duration);
}
```

Every scale (denoted as a major scale for this purpose) has 7 notes. The C-Major Scale for example has the notes:

```
C, D, E, F, G, A, and B
```

If you are to use this scale with the algorithm above to transpose notes such as, for example, a 'B' note on an octave of 5 one up in the C-Major Scale, the algorithm would work as intended and return the note 'C' (index 0 of the scale) on an octave of 6.

However, say that we used the D-Major Scale which consists of the notes

```
D, E, F♯, G, A, B, and C♯
```

For this scale, the last note 'C♯' is supposed to be considered an octave higher than the rest of the notes in the scale. If we were to use the algorithm above to transpose the note 'B' (index 6) on an octave of 5 one up, for example, the algorithm would actually give the note 'C♯' on an octave of 5 which is completely wrong: it should be on the octave of 6.

```
Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
// Prints: [Note: [pitch: C#],[octave: 5]]
System.out.println(original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, 1));
```

Is there any way to fix the algorithm above so that it would support such cases as the above?

The Java classes which I am using for the `Note` and `Pitch` and `Scale` class can be found here: [Jamie Craane Melody Generation - GoogleCode](https://code.google.com/p/melodycomposition/source/browse/trunk/melodycomposition/#melodycomposition%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fnl%2Fjamiecraane%2Fmelodygeneration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently test the `pitch` (i.e. the index in the `scale`) to see if you need to change octave.

But a single scale can contain more than one octave index, and that depends on the index of the note itself relative to C. I'm not using the terminology of that library here as I'm not too familiar with it. So, you need to know if the note's index relative to C has wrapped (down or up) in order to change the octave (up or down).

First assume that you never move more than a `transposeFactor` value of `6`. Next define some tests (see below) before writing any code. And then I think you just need a small change to use `Pitch.getNoteNumber()` which returns the note index relative to C. I also assume that your `getNoteByScale` method is a method on `Note`, and `getScaleIndex` is a method you created on `Scale` as per the below:

```
// this is a method on Scale
public int getScaleIndex(Pitch pitch) {
    return notesInScale.indexOf(pitch);
}
...
public Note getNoteByScale(Scale scale, int transposeFactor) {
    // rename to "newPitchIndex" to distinguish from the actual new Pitch object
    int newPitchIndex = scale.getScaleIndex(this.pitch) + transposeFactor;
    // only use pitch indexes for a scale in the range 0-6
    if (newPitchIndex > 6) newPitchIndex -=7;
    else if (newPitchIndex < 0) newPitchIndex += 7;
    // create the new Pitch object
    Pitch newPitch = scale.getNotesInScale().get(newPitchIndex);

    //  Get the note numbers (relative to C)
    int noteNumber = this.pitch.getNoteNumber();
    int newNoteNumber = newPitch.getNoteNumber();
    int newOctave = this.octave;
    if      (transposeFactor > 0 && newNoteNumber < noteNumber) newOctave++;
    else if (transposeFactor < 0 && newNoteNumber > noteNumber) newOctave--;

    return Note.createNote(newPitch, newOctave, this.duration);
}
```

Now that we have this we can easily extend it to move more than octave at a time. None of this would really have been that easy without the tests:

```
public Note getNoteByScale(Scale scale, int transposeFactor) {
    // move not by more than 7
    int pitchIndex = scale.getScaleIndex(this.pitch);
    int newPitchIndex = (pitchIndex + transposeFactor) % 7;
    // and adjust negative values down from the maximum index
    if (newPitchIndex < 0) newPitchIndex += 7;
    // create the new Pitch object
    Pitch newPitch = scale.getNotesInScale().get(newPitchIndex);

    //  Get the note numbers (relative to C)
    int noteNumber = this.pitch.getNoteNumber();
    int newNoteNumber = newPitch.getNoteNumber();
    //  Get the number of whole octave changes
    int octaveChanges = transposeFactor / 7;
    int newOctave = this.octave + octaveChanges;
    //  Adjust the octave based on a larger/smaller note index relative to C
    if      (transposeFactor > 0 && newNoteNumber < noteNumber) newOctave++;
    else if (transposeFactor < 0 && newNoteNumber > noteNumber) newOctave--;

    return Note.createNote(newPitch, newOctave, this.duration);
}
```

More tests are needed than this, but this is a good starter, and all these do pass:

```
@Test
public void transposeUpGivesCorrectPitch() {
    //                 ┌~1▼
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, 1);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getPitch(), actual.getPitch());
}

@Test
public void transposeDownGivesCorrectPitch() {
    //                 ▼1~┐                     
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, -1);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getPitch(), actual.getPitch());
}

@Test
public void transposeUpOutsideScaleGivesCorrectPitch() {
    //                 ┌‒1‒~2‒‒3‒‒4▼         
    // ║C  D  E  F  G  A  B ║C  D  E  F  G  A  B |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.A, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.C_MAJOR, 4);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.E, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getPitch(), actual.getPitch());
}

@Test
public void transposeDownOutsideScaleGivesCorrectPitch() {
    //           ▼4‒‒3‒‒2‒‒1~┐                        
    // ║C  D  E  F  G  A  B ║C  D  E  F  G  A  B |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.C, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.C_MAJOR, -4);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.F, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getPitch(), actual.getPitch());
}

@Test
public void transposeUpGivesCorrectOctave() {
    //                 ┌~1▼
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, 1);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}

@Test
public void transposeUp2GivesCorrectOctave() {
    //                 ┌~1‒‒2‒‒3‒‒4‒‒5‒‒6‒‒7‒~1▼                     
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, 1 + 7);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 7, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}

@Test
public void transposeDownGivesCorrectOctave() {
    //                 ▼1~┐                     
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, -1);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}

@Test
public void transposeDown2GivesCorrectOctave() {
    //                 ▼1~‒7‒‒6‒‒5‒‒4‒‒3‒‒2‒‒1~┐                     
    // |D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯|D  E  F♯ G  A  B ║C♯ |
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, -1 - 7);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 4, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}

// ... and more tests are needed ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you dont want +1 the octave when you pass the end of the scale (ScaleIndex 7 in this example). You want to +1 the octave when you pass C.

EDIT:

I haven't programmed in java for a long time, I don't have an IDE installed for it, so some I'm gonna write some pseudocode (without types). Also this only works for positive transposefactors, it should be easily adjustable for negatives, but I didn't want to obscure it any more.
The idea is to first know how many full scales we go up, that means we have to add at least that many octaves. 
Then add the rest (which must be smaller than one full scale), and see if we passed C when adding that one. We do that by looking at the notenumber, if the new notenumber is smaller than the old one, we must have passed C.

```
public Note getNoteByScale(Scale scale, int transposeFactor) {
    numberOfNotesInScale = scale.getNotesInScale().size();
    numberOfScalesToTraverseAtLeast = transposeFactor / number_of_notes_in_scale;  // this should be integer division
    newOctave = this.octave + numberOfScalesToTraverseAtLeast;
    restAfterDivide = transposeFactor % numberOfNotesInScale;
    newScaleIndex = (scale.getScaleIndex(this.pitch) + restAfterDivide) % numberOfNotesInScale;  // we are not gonna do +1 when we pass the end of the scale, so just do a modulo on the number of notes of the scale
    newPitch = scale.getNotesInScale().get(newScaleIndex)
    if (newPitch.getNoteNumber < this.pitch.getNoteNumber)  // then we have passed C, so another octave
        newOctave++;

    return Note.createNote(scale.getNotesInScale().get(newPitch), newOctave, this.duration);

}
```

This would be an ideal candidate function for some test driven development, I would at least write a bunch of unittests around it ;)

Comment: Right; in the Pitch class, C is the very start note of an octave and B is the last. However, I was wondering how I could structure the algorithm to work around for this sort of matter.

Comment: FWIW Emile that's not far off. It requires a fair amount of massaging to make it correct Java but it will pass the tests I wrote to move up one or two octaves.

Comment: Highlight code and hit **{ }** in the edit menu for code blocks, or indent code by four spaces. That way you don't have to worry about escaping < and > [Code Blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I know this is an old question, but I needed something similar.  Basically the problem can be decomposed to the following: given a Note ("D") and a number of positive or negative half steps (1), return a new note that is the original note transposed (D#)

The answers here are too complicated.

Try this:

```
public class Transposer {

    enum TARGET { FLAT, SHARP };
    static String[] SHARPS = { "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#" };
    static String[] FLATS  = { "A", "Bb", "B", "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab" };

    static String transpose(String note, int halfSteps, TARGET target) {
        if (target == null) {
            // By default we like flats
            target = TARGET.FLAT;
        }

        String[] scale = FLATS;
        if (target == TARGET.SHARP) {
            scale = SHARPS;
        }

        int index = findIndex(scale, note);
        if (index < 0) return note; // Not found, just return note


        String everythingelse = "";
        if (note.length() > scale[index].length()) {
           everythingelse = note.substring(scale[index].length());
        }


        index = index + halfSteps;
        while (index < 0) {
            index += scale.length;  // Make the index positive
        }
        index = index % scale.length;
        return scale[index]+everythingelse;
    }

    public static int findIndex(String[] scale, String note) {
        int r = -1;
        String root = note.substring(0,1);
        if (note.charAt(1) == '#' || note.charAt(1) == 'b') {
            root = note.substring(0,2);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<scale.length; ++i) {
            if (scale[i].equalsIgnoreCase(root)) {
                // Match.
                return i;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String note = args[0];
        int halfsteps = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println(note+" transposed "+halfsteps+" halfsteps is "+transpose(note, halfsteps, TARGET.FLAT));
    }
}
```

The main() is the test:

```
java -cp . Transposer A 1
A transposed 1 halfsteps is Bb

java -cp . Transposer Eb -3
Eb transposed -3 halfsteps is C

java -cp Transposer C7 2
C7 transposed 2 halfsteps is D7
```

It is trivial to adopt a scale:

```
    String[] scale = { "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B" };
    for (String snote: scale) {
      System.out.print(Transposer.transpose(snote,1,null));
    }
    System.out.println();

=> Db Eb F Gb Ab Bb C
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your scale and then use it. Like this all of the scale pitches are in the same octave. This is the simplest solution in my eyes.

```
public Note getNoteByScale(Scale scale, int transposeFactor) {
       List<Pitch> tempScale=new ArrayList<Pitch>(scale.getNotesInScale());

       Collections.sort(tempScale,new Comparator<Pitch>(){
                             @Override
                             public int compare(Pitch a,Pitch b){
                                 if(a.getNoteNumber() == b.getNoteNumber()){
                                     return 0;
                                 }else if(a.getNoteNumber() > b.getNoteNumber()){
                                     return 1;
                                 }else{
                                     return -1;   
                                 }
                             }

       });

       int index = (tempScale.indexOf(this.pitch) + transposeFactor );

       int newPitch  = ((index % 7)+7)%7;
       int newOctave;
       if(index>0){
           newOctave = this.octave + index/7;
       }else{
           newOctave = this.octave + (index-6)/7;
       }


       return Note.createNote(tempScale.get(newPitch),
            newOctave, this.duration);
    }
```

**EDIT: Now it passes all the tests**

Added two cases to the Unit tests of @AndyBrown:

```
@Test
public void transposeDown6GivesCorrectOctave() {
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 6, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, -1-7-7-7-7-7);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 0, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}

@Test
public void transposeUp5GivesCorrectOctave() {
    Note original = Note.createNote(Pitch.B, 5, Duration.WHOLE);
    Note actual = original.getNoteByScale(Scale.D_MAJOR, 1+7+7+7+7);
    Note expected = Note.createNote(Pitch.C_SHARP, 10, Duration.WHOLE);
    assertEquals(expected.getOctave(), actual.getOctave());
}
```

Comment: Although idealistically it may work, sorting the scale would actually give logic errors in terms of applying the system to actual musical notes. If I were to disrupt the order of a major scale in this case and transpose notes around the sorted scale, it would be difficult to structure chords and melodies.

Then again, I am really thankful for the answer, but I believe it still remains error-prone in terms of its applications in music theory.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't `sort(scale)`. As @KentaIwasaki says you also need to sort a clone, not the original. If you extract the `Pitch`s from `scale` first then you would need a custom `Comparator`, or to make `Pitch` implement `Comparable`. Other than that, this would work (but needs changes to go down octaves as well).

Comment: @AndyBrown thanks for the pointers. I adjusted my answer according to your input. If I'm correct it should work for all cases now, but I'd have to run nice Unit tests to be sure as you did.

Comment: @FlyingSwissman. Note (pun not intended) that you can just return a [-ve, 0 or +ve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) from `Comparator.compare(a,b)`, so you could just do `return a.getNoteNumber() - b.getNoteNumber();`. In this case, due to the range of possible values from `getNoteNumber()` there is no risk of overflow, so it is a perfectly safe way to implement `compare(a,b)`